# Use of "trace add variable read" in tcl

Tags: tcl

New to tcl and trying to understand the "trace add variable" command.

I understand the need to invoke a callback function when a variable is "written" to.

But what is the use of the "read" option? For debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example use might be a global counter:

```
proc init { } {
  set ::globalcounter 0
  trace add variable ::globalcounter read ::gcountUpdate
}

proc gcountUpdate { } {
  incr ::globalcounter
}

proc main { } {
  init
  puts $::globalcounter
  puts $::globalcounter
}
main
```

I'm sure there are other uses.  As you pointed out, debugging.
It could be used for enforcement of variable access by specific procedures.

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses for read callbacks (which are indeed quite a bit less common than write callbacks) is in linking a Tcl variable to a C variable; the read callback is used to enforce the reading of the C variable and synchronizing the Tcl variable to it. (The write callback would ensure that the update of the Tcl variable gets reflected to the C variable.) Tcl's got [a built-in C API](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/LinkVar.htm) that uses this mechanism, though it's using the underlying C API for variable traces rather than the Tcl API that is built on top of it.

You could also use a read callback to make an apparently read-only variable:

```
trace add variable foo read {apply {args {
    upvar "#0" foo v
    set v "definitely this"
}}}

puts $foo
set foo "that"
puts $foo
```

I don't recommend using variable traces on local variables. They have a lot more overhead (and internal complexity) than for global/namespace variables.